# Team reputation from deleted answer gone after recalc

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, stack-overflow-for-teams

On a private Team instance, I posted an answer, which got upvoted but I later deleted. I noticed that I had retained the rep from it after (even though my answer was <30 days old - based on [the help page](https://www.stackoverflow.help/support/solutions/articles/36000042869-reputation#lose) I believe that's WAI). However, when I looked at my profile today all that rep was gone...

Is this intentional, and my keeping the rep was a fluke? Or possibly an unintended side effect of the recent [reputation recalculations](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/)?

<sup>(P.S. I've undeleted the answer now to see if my rep would come back, no changes yet - though I do see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KGRQ.png).. fun with caching?)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. Anytime a user is removed or content is deleted, the reputation gains are rolled back. Previously, reputation recalcs were not continuously run, but now run more frequently due to the current recalculations.

Keeping rep from a deleted answer was indeed a fluke.